# MongoDB connection error AND Insufficient free space for journal files

Tags: server, partitioning, virtualization, mongodb, grunt

I installed a VMWare Ubuntu 64-bit virtual machine and grunt with mongoDB.

Everything worked fine and one day when I typed "grunt serve" as always, I got:

```
Debugger listening on port 5858
Express server listening on 9000, in development mode

Running "wait" task
Waiting for server reload...
MongoDB connection error: MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
Stopping Express server
```

After I typed `mongod` I got:

```
ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
```

---

I tried everything written in previous topics including reinstalling mongo and the whole VM.
Adding --smallfiles in mongod.conf doesn't work as well. Also, when I type the df command the output suggests that I don't have any partition which is full.

df command output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the MongoDB data directory is full.
Please check the configuration file of MongoDB and find the data directory and see whether there is enough space in it.

Comment: You're probably right. I checked the free space in my /data/db directory (as was written in the mongo.conf file) with du -sh and it says I have 81M available. After typing mongod the error message says I have to ensure at least 3000+ MB, so I guess this is indeed the problem.
I see two files in this folder that are quite big, but I don't know whether it's safe to delete them: local.0 and local.ns

Comment: I deleted some old kernels and the 'Insufficient free space' message dissapered after i typed mongod, but grunt serve is still not working. The output of mongod now is: connections:0

Comment: OK, so i can start mongo service and apparantely no one is waiting to connect. However, when I type sudo status mongodb I get:
status: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

Comment: Connection refused means it was not running. Try to perform ps -ef | grep mongod

Answer (score 0):

Do you have apropriate rights to write to mongodb data directory - user which starts mongod has rights to write to mongodb data directory ?